# Trouble with web scraping a map Python, Splinter

Tags: python, web-scraping, splinter

I am trying to get data from [this](https://ndismaps.nrel.colostate.edu/index.html?app=FishingAtlas) but I can't find a way to go through each point with information on the map. What happens is my program selects the same multiple times instead of selecting multiple points one time. So if I have a range(10) it doesn't select 10 different points on the map. Is there a workaround for this issue? Also, I am new to programming and self-taught so explanations would be appreciated.

```
from splinter import Browser
import time

def dismiss_disclaimer(browser):
    time.sleep(1)
    checkbox = browser.find_by_xpath("//*[@id='showDisclaimer']")
    accept = browser.find_by_xpath("//*[@id='dijit_form_Button_0_label']")

    checkbox.check()
    accept.click()


def grab_popup_info(browser):
    time.sleep(.5)
    map_point = browser.find_by_tag('svg')
    map_point.click()
    time.sleep(.5)
    popup = browser.find_by_xpath('//*[@id="mapDiv_root"]/div[3]/div[1]').value
    return popup


with Browser('chrome') as browser:
    url = "https://ndismaps.nrel.colostate.edu/index.html?app=FishingAtlas"
    browser.visit(url)

    dismiss_disclaimer(browser)

    time.sleep(1)

    popups = [grab_popup_info(browser) for x in range(10)]
```